# Executing R script from Azure function

Tags: r, azure-functions, azure-machine-learning-service

I want to execute a R script every time an azure function is triggered. The R script executes perfectly on Azure machine learning Studio. But I am failing to execute through azure function.
Is there any way to execute it?

Comment: Does this help? https://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2020/12/azure-functions-with-r.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you'll have to create your own Runtime as `R` isn't supported natively.

Have you already tried ["Create a function on Linux using a custom container"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image?tabs=bash%2Cportal&pivots=programming-language-other)? Interestingly they have given `R` as the example of custom runtime, so hopefully that answers your question.

Comment: yap! Microsoft Doc - [Create a function on Linux using a custom container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image?tabs=in-process%2Cbash%2Cazure-cli&pivots=programming-language-other) works for me. The solution is to use docker container!